# Difference between AzureAD and AzureADPreview PowerShell Modules?

Tags: powershell, module, azure-active-directory

What is the difference between these two modules?

- `AzureAD` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0
- `AzureADPreview` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0-preview

They're not compatible and their descriptions on MSDN are nearly identical.

I would assume that `AzureAD` replaces `AzureADPreview`, but then what would be the equivalent of the `Get-AzureADPolicy` and `Get-AzureADPolicyAppliedObject` commands from the `AzureADPreview` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AzureADPreview is where new updates are shipped first.
AzureAD module gets updated later.

You can see the version numbers in PowerShell Gallery: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.2.118 and https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.2.119 are newest at time of writing. (2.0.2.118 for AzureAD and 2.0.2.119 for AzureADPreview)

Comment: Hmmm that is not at all what I expected. The commands I mentioned were used over a year ago, it seems odd that they're not in the standard version yet. Thank you for the explanation, it definitely helps.

Comment: Okay that is definitely odd :\